# In TestNG, @test(enabled=True). I want to change the enabled value(true/false) at run time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, boolean, testng

Im working on TestNG and I actually want to parametrize the 'enabled' as true/false, so that I can run intimidated @test only.I tried out with pass value using final boolean type, but I cannot change the value. I'm using excel for externalizing the test data, please suggest me solution.

```
@Test(enabled=true)
public void TC_00() throws Exception {          
            class.somemethod();     
        }
@Test(enabled=false)
public void TC_01() throws Exception {
            class.somemethod();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Annotation transformers](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) are for you!